# DIvisibility Error in the TI-84

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, prime-factorization, calculator

I am trying to factorize a large number,

$$600851475143$$

So I just started trying primes and in my TI-84, I got that

$$600851475143=61\cdot 9850024183$$

so then I got

$$9850024183=7\cdot 1407146312$$

Which can't be possible since this implies the original number is even as a factor is even itself.  When checking other sources, it is clear $61$ is NOT a prime factor.  But why then would my calculator give an incorrect factor to begin with?

Comment: $600851475143\ne 61\cdot 9850024183$. Your calculator simply rounded the resulting value of $9850024182+\frac{41}{61}$.

Comment: 600851475143 is not a multiple of 61

Comment: Surely all of this is due to floating point errors?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown It's not an error, most handheld calculators display results to $10$ significant figures.

Comment: Is there a certain number size that this occurs with?

Comment: Any number with more than $10$ significant digits will not be displayed accurately on your calculator as it can only display results to this level of accuracy.

Comment: There is no way for a product of 7 and an even number to be odd, so the second equation is also incorrect

Comment: Were you trying to do this by trial division, going through the primes in order? Clearly 600851475143 is not divisible by 2 or by 5, but I would still try dividing it by 3. What does the Ti-84 tell you? 200283825047.67? 200283825048? And what about dividing by 7? 85835925020.42? Or just 85835925020?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often cases such as this are caused by [floating point error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples), which is worth being familiar with. In this case, however, it is highly unlikely that floating point error is at all relevant, given the scale of these computations. <s>What seems to be more likely is that you have a display precision setting active on your calculator, which is causing you calculator to round answer before displaying them. You may want to navigate to the `MODE` menu and check which setting is highlighted on the third line that reads `FLOAT 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.</s>

Correction: the TI-84 series can only display 10 significant figures regardless of display settings. You may wish to use a different device to perform these computations, such as a computer algebra system like [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), in order to make use of greater precision. This has the added benefit of allowing you to automate many common tasks. For instance, you can trivially factor any integer in sage with the following:

```
sage: factor(600851475143)
71 * 839 * 1471 * 6857
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, there is also the `remainder` function which can be found under `MATH>NUM>0:remainder(` which can be used to more effectively test the divisibility of two integers.

Comment: FLOAT was highlighted.

Comment: So since it only goes from 1-9, I can never use the TI-84 to do large number divisibility essentially.

Comment: @Lalaloopsy If you use the remainder function (http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/remainder), you can find out whether a number $a$ is divisible by another number $b$ because if $b|a$ then $\text{remainder(a,b)=0}$.

Comment: Never knew about that remainder function.  And that does return a remainder of 41.  Nice.   Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

long division saves the day... BTW that's tiny compared to what you can attempt once you know a bit of theory. 10 digits precision as suggested in the other answer, is also a low amount. On to the long division (using the theory you can changes things by a multiple and have the same remainder):$$\begin{align}9850024182\\61\overline{\big)600851475143}\\\underline{-549}\phantom{000000000}\\518\phantom{00000000}\\\underline{-488}\phantom{00000000}\\305\phantom{0000000}\\\underline{-305}\phantom{0000000}\\0147\phantom{0000}\\\underline{-0122}\phantom{0000}\\255\phantom{000}\\\underline{-244}\phantom{000}\\111\phantom{00}\\\underline{-61}\phantom{00}\\504\phantom{0}\\\underline{-488}\phantom{0}\\163\\\underline{-122}\\41\end{align}$$  which shows it doesn't divide evenly in the first case. ( just a pain to align,without a rewrite)

**Emphasis** A calculator is only as good generally, as it's operator. some calculators don't have order of operations built in for example, you should, it's best left as a checking mechanism in most cases.